# Check chekbox while selecting fdropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list and check box in 2 columns of table and I want to change state of checkbox by updating the dropdown.

Comment: What have you already tried? Some sample code will help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Set the "class" of the checkboxes to the option values. Then you can use jQuery like this:

```
$("select[name='types']").change(function() {
// Get the value selected (convert spaces to underscores for class selection)
var value = $(this).val().replace(' ', '_');

// Clear checks, then check boxes that have class "value"
$(":checkbox").prop("checked",false).filter("."+value).prop("checked",true);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NEESR/

Comment: Thanks. My dropdown is in a table, and I tried ->$('#table').on("change", 'select', (e) => not working

Comment: Nope. `<select name="hello">`. and then `$("select[name='hello']").change(function() {`. You aren't changing the table ¬¬

Comment: i tried,  but may be because my dropdown is inside <table><tr>, it is not working . I am not sure why. I have updated question with example